# Como fazer um "time-slice" em pacotes num dump de rede com Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou tentando "pegar" IPs de origem e IPs de destino dentro de um arquivo PCAP (dump de rede) . A ideia é guardar todos os IPs de origem  e todos os IPS de destino varrendo o arquivo a cada 10 minutos ("time-slice"), por exemplo.

O código abaixo abre o dump ("captura.pcap") e imprime os tempos dos pacotes. Como "separar" os pacotes a cada 10 min?
Não entendi que tempos são esses... Seriam Milesegundo? Que unidade de tempo é usada?

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = rdpcap("captura.pcap")

for p in pkts:
    print p.time
```

A saida é:

```
1488498263.14
1488498263.15
1488498263.15
1488498263.15
1488498263.31
1488498263.31
1488498263.31
1488498263.6
1488498263.78
1488498264.49
1488498264.49
1488498264.49
1488498264.49
1488498264.5
1488498264.5
1488498264.5
1488498264.5
1488498265.07
1488498265.07
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esses valores estão em [timestamp](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_temporal):

Em python2.7 você pode importar o `datetime` para efetuar conversões de `timestamp`

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1488498263.14)
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 2, 20, 44, 23, 140000)
>>>
```

Como exemplo utilizei seu primeiro `timestamp=1488498263.14` repara na notação de retorno da função que é equivalente a ano/mês/dia hora/minutos/segundos = 2/3/2017 20:44:23, é só você pegar os dados do retorno e montar da  maneira que deseja!

Uma maneira de pegar os valores que precisa é não converter o timestamp, se você quer pegar os valores a cada 10 minutos então some o primeiro timestamp + 10 min em timestamp e vá guardando os valores que forem menor ou igual ao valor do timestamp + 10, OK você pegou 10 min de dados, agora para o próximo timestamp você faz a mesma lógica soma o próximo timestamp + 10 novamente e vai caminhando e guardando todos os valores que for menor ou igual e faça isso até o final, a lógica é essa:

Primeiro valor + 10 min de timestamp:

```
1488498263.14+ 10 * 60 = 1488498863.14
```

Caminhe no seu for guardando todos os valores/linhas que for menor ou igual a 1488498863.14, quando achar um valor maior some esse valor + 10 * 60 novamente e armazene todos os valores dentro desse período, faça isso até o fim, não tem maneira fácil use a lógica...

```
pkts = [1488498263.14, 1488498263.15, 1488498263.15, 1488498263.15, 1488498263.31, 1488498263.31, 1488498263.31, 1488498263.6, 1488498263.78, 1488498264.49, 1488498264.49, 1488498264.49, 1488498264.49, 1488498264.5, 1488498264.5, 1488498264.5, 1488498264.5, 1488498265.07, 1488498265.07]


somaMin = pkts[0] + 1

valores=[]
for p in pkts:

    if p<=somaMin:
        #armazenando os valores que estiverem dentro do intervalo de tempo
        valores.append(p)

    else:

        #processe aqui tudo que tem no vetor valores, eles vão conter os dados no intervalo desejado

        #apagando tudo que tem dentro do vetor para receber os próximos dados
        valores=[]
        #armazenando o próximo valor
        valores.append(p)
        #somando o valor novamente
        somaMin=p+ 1

#processe aqui tudo que restou no vetor valores, eles vão conter os dados que sobraram
```

Não tenho todos os dados do seu sniffer, mas usando os dados que você mostrou, tem em torno de 2 segundos, então eu fiz:

```
somaMin = pkts[0] + 1
```

Mas no seu caso altere o somaMin para ser `+ 10 * 60`

```
somaMin = pkts[0] + 10 * 60
```

Não esquece dentro do else também:

```
somaMin=p+ 10 * 60
```

Não consigo ser mais claro que isso lol

Comment: Eu gostaria de varrer o dump pegando os pacotes a cada 10 minutos ate o fim do arquivo. Como fazer de forma simples?]

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: não vai ser mt simples, veja se entende a lógica na resposta....

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorancia. Eu tenho um pouco de dificuldade em enteder. Por favor, não leve a mal!

Comment: huahuahua editei com um código veja se agora você entende ....

Comment: Tentei aqui assim:  http://imgur.com/a/nLnRC

Comment: Só recebo erros:  packets[counter] = temp IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: O que pode ser?

Comment: Primeiro, seu código nao faz sentido, não tem a lógica que vc deseja, segundo o seu counter está passando do tamanho da lista packets alias ela nem existe está sempre vazia, seu código está cheio de erros e bugs, a lógica de como pegar os valores no intervalo que vc precisa está na resposta, siga ela ...

Comment: vou estudar com calma a resposta. Posso tirar duvidas amanha? vou tentar fazer sem olhar

Comment: OK pode sim :-)

Comment: Eu tentei rodar aqui com o dump e deu este erro: " somaMin = pkts[0] + 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Ether' and 'int'"

Comment: deveria ser pkts[0].time + 1, lembre eu não tenho seu arquivo, meu código funciona com o vetor dos valores que vc mostrou, adapte para o q precisa ai ...

Comment: obrigado! Estou tentando adicionar outra funcionalidade ao código acima. Para não alongar aqui, vou criar agora outra pergunta!