# Como filtrar arquivo PCAP com Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, redes

O arquivo PCAP foi gerado em 21/12/2016 e tem 5 GB e assim, é impraticável tentar abri-lo com wireshark (interface gráfica)

Instalei o tshark no Ubuntu e ao ler o manual, tentei fazer o seguinte filtro:

```
 tshark -r capture21dez2016.pcap -Y '((frame.time >= "2016-12-21 11:15:00") && (frame.time <= "2016-12-21 12:14:00.000000000"))'  -w 11h15_12h14_semAtaques.pcap
```

E funcionou. Como utilizar o filtro acima no código Python abaixo?

```
from scapy.all import *
import dpkt

f = open("capture21dez2016.pcap")
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe mágica, o tshark foi esperto e leu o arquivo em pedaços utilizando ponteiros.

O tshark foi escrito em C e certamente possui uma performance melhor em loops do que python o fato é que o tshark  teve que alocar pedaços ou buffers na memória para ler o arquivo pedaço por pedaço e ir separando os dados dentro do intervalo de interesse.

Essa linha `pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)` fala para  o Python ler o arquivo inteiro e colocar tudo na variável pcap, ou seja se vira para alocar 5GB de dados :-(

A maneira esperta de se fazer é mover o ponteiro de leitura para alguma outra parte do arquivo para que você possa ler a partir do local apontado.

Em python é possível fazer isso:

```
from scapy.all import *
import dpkt

f = open("capture21dez2016.pcap")


pcap = f.read(4096)
while pcap:

    #processe cada pedaço aqui

    pcap = f.read(4096)

f.close()
```

repara na linha `pcap = f.read(4096)` estamos abrindo o arquivo por pedaços, para ser exato a cada 4096 bytes, o `f.read()` usa ponteiro para saber onde exatamente foi a ultima posição lida para sempre começar a ler o arquivo da ultima posição, você pode definir quantos bytes por vez quer ler, eu utilizei 4096 para exemplificar. Você pode continuar utilizando o código dessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187565/como-fazer-um-time-slice-em-pacotes-num-dump-de-rede-com-python) para achar o seu intervalo de interesse, converta a sua data e hora de interesse em timestamp para ficar mais fácil e lembre-se se você já achou os dados dentro do intervalo desejado você pode sair do loop e não precisa mais ler o resto do arquivo :-)

Comment: um dos problemas que estou enfrentando aqui neste projeto é justamente o uso de memória. Quando eu rodava o script, o consumo batia 95% RAM (o notebook tem 8GB).... Vou testar aqui. Muito obrigado